# How do integers multiply in C++?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, math

I was wondering what kind of method was used to multiply numbers in C++. Is it the traditional schoolbook long multiplication? [Fürer's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%BCrer%27s_algorithm)? [Toom-Cook](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toom%E2%80%93Cook_multiplication)?

I was wondering because I am going to need to be multiplying extremely large numbers and need a high degree of efficiency. Therefore the traditional schoolbook long multiplication `O(n^2)` might be too inefficient, and I would need to resort to another method of multiplication.

So what kind of multiplication does C++ use?

Comment: Whatever the chip does, it does.

Comment: The title made me think of integers reproducing :)

Comment: @harold First they must do something called "dating."

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You seem to be missing several crucial things here:

1. There's a difference between ***native*** arithmetic and ***bignum*** arithmetic.
2. You seem to be interested in ***bignum*** arithmetic.
3. C++ doesn't support ***bignum*** arithmetic. The primitive datatypes are generally ***native*** arithmetic to the processor.

To get bignum (arbitrary precision) arithmetic, you need to implement it yourself or use a library. (such as [GMP](http://gmplib.org/)) Unlike Java, and C# (among others), C++ does not have a library for arbitrary precision arithmetic.

All of those fancy algorithms:

- Karatsuba: `O(n^1.585)`
- Toom-Cook: `< O(n^1.465)`
- FFT-based: `~ O(n log(n))`

are applicable only to bignum arithmetic which are implemented in bignum libraries. What the processor uses for its native arithmetic operations is somewhat irrelevant as it's 
usually constant time.

---

In any case, I don't recommend that you try to implement a bignum library. I've done it before and it's quite demanding (especially the math). So you're better off using a library.

Comment: Until you get to very big numbers, the method you learned in grade school will perform better in practice. Of course you use a larger base than 10. :-) Depending on your needs, 2^32, 2^64, or 10^9 make convenient bases (a power of 10 is useful is parsing/printing your numbers in base 10 is important to optimize, and 10^9 is the largest power that fits in 32 bits).

Answer (score 3):

What do you mean by "extremely large numbers"?

C++, like most other programming languages, uses the multiplication hardware that is built-in in the processor. Exactly how that works is not specified by the C++ language. But for normal integers and floating-point numbers, you will not be able to write something faster in software.

The largest numbers that can be represented by the various data types can vary between different implementations, but some typical values are 2147483647 for **int**, 9223372036854775807 for **long**, and 1.79769e+308 for **double**.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ integer multiplication is handled by the chip.  There is no equivalent of Perl's BigNum in the standard language, although I'm certain such libraries do exist.

Comment: To nitpick: Not necessarily. It's perfectly possible for implementations to include numeric types (even `int`, though *that* should be rather rare) which the architecture targeted does not support, and instead implement arithmetic operations on them as calls into some runtime library. Consider 128-bit integers, or possibly 64-bit integers on 32-bit systems. Also, there used to be many chips without floating point unit (FPU).

Comment: @delnan: Rare, but not nonexistent: the 8-bit 6502 processor has no 16-bit arithmetic instructions, so the CC65 C compiler has to implement `int` arithmetic through sequences of 8-bit instructions and library calls.

Answer (score 0):

That all depends on the library and compiler used.

Answer (score 0):

It is performed in hardware. for the same reason huge numbers won't work. The largest number c++ can represent in 64 bit hardware is 18446744073709551616. if you need larger numbers you need an arbitrary precision library.

Comment: What about doubles? Besides, the exact size of most data types is up to the compiler. I also believe some compilers offer 128-bit integer types.

Answer (score 0):

plain c++ uses CPU mult instructions (or schoolbook multiplication using bitshifts and additions if your CPU does not have such an instruction. )

if you need fast multiplication for large numbers, I would suggest looking at gmp ( http://gmplib.org ) and use the c++ interface from gmpxx.h

Answer (score 0):

If you work with large numbers the standard integer multiplication in c++ will no longer work and you should use a library providing arbitrary precision multiplication, like GMP http://gmplib.org/

Also, you should not worry about performance prior to writing your application (=premature optimization). These multiplications will be fast, and most likely many other components in your software will cause much more slowdown.

Answer (score 0):

Just how big are these numbers going to be? Even languages like python can do `1e100*1e100` with arbitrary precision integers over 3 million times a second on a standard processor. That's multiplication to 100 significant places taking less than one millionth of second. To put that into context there are only about 10^80 atoms in the observable universe.

Write what you want to achieve first, and optimise later if necessary.